# asp.net + Viewstate and comma delimited string

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I have read about many articles on how a page gets bog down by excessive usage of Viewstate, I am not sure if using a comma delimited string of maybe 3 - 4 words and splitting it to an array

```
string s = 'john,23,usa';
string[] values = s.Split(',');
```

for retrieval is going to help as I have seen many of my colleagues are doing that presumably trying to improve page loading performance. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it does make difference in some cases, but it seems tricky and often irrelevant.
 See the cases below:

The examples show the `ViewState` size in bytes, meaning that a page without anything results on a 68 bytes `ViewState`.
Everything else is the content manually loaded to the `ViewState`.

Putting a string value of 0..9999 on `ViewState`.

```
string x = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    if (i != 0) x += ",";

    x += i;
}

//x = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...9999"
ViewState["x"] = x;

//Result = 65268 bytes
```

And with an array:

```
string[] x = new string[10000];

for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    x[i] = i.ToString();
}

ViewState["x"] = x;

//Result = also 65268 bytes
```

Both cases above result in a 65260 bytes `ViewState` when returned on the overridable `SaveViewState` method. 8 bytes less than loading it on the `ViewState` object.

However, in some other case:

```
//104 bytes
ViewState["x"] = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" 

// 108 bytes
ViewState["x"] = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" , "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}
```

If you override the page `SaveViewState` method:

```
protected override object SaveViewState()
{
    //100 bytes
    return new string[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" };

    //100 bytes
    return "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
}
```

As the `ViewState` is encrypted and `Base64 encoded,` in some cases it could be just a matter of string encoding two different objects that generates two different outputs to the page.